# Spring Validation Errors for RequestParam

Tags: spring, spring-validator

I want to pass org.springframework.validation.Errors to CodeValidator class.
But, since I am not using RequestBody/RequestPart/ModelAttribute, I cannot put Errors in method param after variable.

I use @RequestParam for code variable, and I want to validate that using CodeValidator class that implement org.springframework.validation.Validator.

Here is my code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/check-code", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Object> checkCode(@RequestParam("code") String code, Errors errors) {
    codeValidator.validate(code, errors);
    if(errors.hasErrors()) {
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Errors");
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok("");
}
```

and here error result for my code:
`An Errors/BindingResult argument is expected to be declared immediately after the model attribute, the @RequestBody or the @RequestPart arguments to which they apply: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.example.myapp.controller.CodeController.checkCode(java.lang.String,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult)`
what should I do to be able using CodeValidator with @RequestParam?

Updated:
Code for CodeValidator

```
@Service
public class CodeValidator implements Validator {
    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        String code = ((String) target);

        if(code == null || code.isEmpty()) {            
            errors.rejectValue("code", "", "Please fill in Code.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you create an annotation with your validator? 
Otherwise take a look at a small example/tutorial for custom validating with spring: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator

(edit) if you are using spring boot you might need add a MethodValidationPostProcessor bean to your spring config to enable custom valdation for the @requesParam

Comment: Yes, I am using annotation in CodeValidator as you can see I have been added code. There is no problem with codeValidator autowired.